# Political humor

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Would it be possible to add humor based flagged questions that are not serious in nature, not quite open threads, but would be variations on a theme, just to get the crowd sourcing response.  Something like "Did Hillary just get schlonged by Weiner?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because this would contradict the very nature of StackExchange.

**We are here to learn.** To learn from facts, not from someone's sharp tongue and a quick wit.
There are plenty of political-related chat boards and forums around, and humorous posts here would only dilute the valuable information.

[Exceptioุุุุ้้้ns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/974789) from this rule are very rare. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing I know of on a Stack Exchange site is Mi Yodeya (Judaism) and their [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) policy. As part of a cultural tradition, they have a few weeks out of the year where they can ask humorous questions, but only with strict guidelines about the nature of the humor (e.g. a misinterpretation of the Torah).

If we allow political humor, I think we would also have to set guidelines as to what kinds of humor is allowed (we don't want rude or offensive humor. I also think it would be a difficult to moderate.

Additionally, we don't want to change the goal of the site. Mi Yodeya is primarily a site about serious questions, so Purim Torah questions must be closed at the end of the allowed period. I think that this site is about serious questions, so we don't want to encourage it to become a humor site.

Answer (score -3):

No.

Comment: *sigh*. A 1-word answer with zero argumentation on Meta gets 4 upvotes (whether it's because it's by a moderator, or because people dislike the question, or questioner, or a combination thereof). Everything that's wrong with SE, in one short example. **It doesn't matter if you agree with the answer, a 1-word answer shouldn't be upvoted**.